# Чи можна вживати слово "атаман"?

Tags: вживання-слів

> Атаман - старший в роду і ватажок у степових народів, ватажок козаків
> або (застар.) взагалі старший у справі. Слово походить від тюркського
> слова «ата» - «батько», «дід» з особовим закінченням «ман» («мен») і
> буквально означає «я-батько», «я дід» що в патріархальному тюркською
> суспільстві було рівносильно твердженню «я (тут) головний».

Інформацію взято з [сайту](http://wiki.kubg.edu.ua/%D0%90%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD) Київського університету ім. Б. Грінченка. На жаль, в СУМі такого слова мені не вдалося знайти і там є лише "отаман". [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD) пише:

> Чинні варіанти вимови і написання — отама́н, ота́ман, атама́н.

Також знаходимо це слово в [словнику Грінченка](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD) і в "Енеїді" Котляревського:

> Урядники з **атаманами**
>
> Новими чванились шапками,

Також знайшов цікаву інформацію в пості на [Фейсбуці](https://www.facebook.com/pravopys/posts/809126782532764:0):

> Слово «отаман» має тюркські корені: прийшло до нас від
> кримськотатарського ataman «великий батько, найстарший», що має корінь
> ata «батько» і збільшуваний наросток -man. Не дивно також, що в деяких
> словниках присутні форми «атаман» і «гатаман», що аж ніяк не
> суперечить традиції української мови передавати через «а» етимологічну
> літеру «а» та етимологічну «о» перед складом із наголошеною «а»:
> багатий, ганчар, гаразд, калач, кажан, паламар, чабан, шаравари;
> манастир, кавун. Написання «ганчар», «манастир» «шаравари», до речи,
> було офіційним до 1945 року. А форма з протезою «г» («гатаман»)
> свідчить про поширеність серед людей форми з «а», бо тільки повністю
> засвоєні українською мовою слова мають здатність до протезації,
> порівняйте: (в)ирій, (в)іслюк, (в)угілля, (г)икавка, (г)индик,
> (г)оробець. З української мови «отаман» проникло в сусідні мови,
> зокрема й у російську, яка вже понесла його до инших до тюркомовців
> (татарів, казаків, азербайджанців і киргизів). Ось така невеличка
> історія цього слова.
>
> Але офіційно пишемо тільки «отаман».

То чи можна вживати слово "атаман" чи краще повністю його замінити словом "отаман"?

Comment: Гадаьу, красше таки розріжньати _отоман_ і _атаман_ ьак _козак_ і _казак_ шчо можливо з _kazak_ чи _kazaq_ — навііть ье _Казакстан_. Варто зазначити, шчо тут справа не лише в протезі, а ь в гармоніьі голосних — властиве дльа тьурських мов, а не словьанським (хоча місцьами теж видно, але переважно від впливу тіьеьі ж тьурських).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На мою думку краще вживати лише слово "отаман", адже воно присутнє в таких словниках:

[УСЕ (Універсальний словник-енциклопедія)](http://slovopedia.org.ua/29/53406/17434.html)

[Великий тлумачний словник (ВТС) сучасної української мови](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53406/931870.html)

[Словник синонімів Караванського](http://slovopedia.org.ua/41/53406/269798.html)

[Українсько-російський словник](http://slovopedia.org.ua/47/53406/330212.html)

[СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/otaman)

[Орфографічний словник української мови](http://slovopedia.org.ua/35/53406/140340.html)

Слово "атаман" відсутнє в цих словниках.